# Add ARM Service Endpoint programatically in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an existing SPN in Azure AD and want to add to VSTS **programatically**. 
Is this possible?
VSTS Rest-API? Examples?
Through powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API to manage your endpoints.

For example the following POST will create an Azure endpoint:

https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultAgileGitProject/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=4.1-preview.1

```
{
  "data": {
    "SubscriptionId": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456129012",
    "SubscriptionName": "TestSubscriptionName"
  },
  "id": "64be39c2-102b-416d-a3ac-2de40ebc8513",
  "name": "TestEndpoint",
  "type": "Azure",
  "authorization": {
    "parameters": {
      "Certificate": "dummyCertificate"
    },
    "scheme": "Certificate"
  },
  "isReady": false
}
```

You can find the full documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1